# Execute Commands / Run Programs

Tags: java, php, joomla, exec, joomla3.0

We've been working on a quite specific coding project recently. What we want to do is:

- Use Java applications to do tasks impossible (or at least very diffucult) to accomplish in PHP
- Control those Java programs with Joomla 3.0

We've found out that there is support for PHP Scripts in Joomla by using [this extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/5051) or we could create our own module by using [this](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/tools/webbased-tools/7627).

**My question is**: Is there a way to call programs / execute commands in a more practical manner than using the PHP functions `shell_exec()` or `exec()` or using `popen()`?
Especially since these Java programs will run under a different user (on a Windows Server ...).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do not use such components. This is dangerous no matter what creator says. I'm Joomla extension developer and believe me it can ruin your application and make more problems and benefits. Depends on what you want to archive and how big will be your project you have few possibilities:

### 1. Create component that will execute commands

Something similar to what U did but based on custom created component. Its fastest and cheapest way. Problem starts when your Java application will use more resources then website (interface). So its more like good solution for start.

### 2. Create component that will contact application written in Java via API

This is good solution if your Java application use a lot of resources. You can run it on several servers, manage servers load so clients gets results faster etc. This gives you many possibilities, flexibility but is 
harder to implement and will cost more.

### 3. Just use applet running on clients computer (if your application allows it)

Simple, effective, costs less but also can be impossible depending on what tasks application have to run.